# Ubuntu package install directory standards

Tags: ubuntu, standards

I've been trying to find some documentation that defines the standard which Ubuntu uses for installing applications.  I'm making a web app that I want to install it in the correct places.

As an example, I've noticed the following directory pattern with MediaWiki.

- configuration files are in /etc/mediawiki
- dynamic files are in /var/lib/mediawiki
- static files are in /usr/share/mediawiki

There seems to be the same standard with other apps, but I have yet to find documentation that says these files go there and not somewhere else.

Does anyone know a good resource for this information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ubuntu, like its parent, Debian, follows the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/). The [Ubuntu policy](http://people.canonical.com/~cjwatson/ubuntu-policy/policy.html/index.html) or [Debian policy](http://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/index.html) manual is the definitive resource for this.